# Device is connected but not showing in particular flutter project why?

Tags: android-studio, adb

Hi I trying to compile a project but it's saying device is not connect but at the same time another project is recognizing the device and everything working fine there Anyone know why?

[image: for more check this picture]

**Edit**

setting the project sdk in file -> project structure will solve this issue

[image]

Comment: Device show in Logcat and toolbar not showing device..?

Comment: Technically yes, In another project everything working fine but in this project, it's not showing any connected devices and the logcat in the picture is belongs to another project.